# Grails - Calling built in constraint from custom validator closure

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-validation

I'd like to be able to have a constraint implemented as optional based on another field of the domain class.

Such that, if `importMode`is true, the company field is no longer required, but if import mode is false the default functionality provided by  `company (blank:false)` is invoked.

```
class MyClass {
    boolean importMode
    String company

    static constraints = {
        company(validator: { val, obj ->
            if(obj.importMode) {
                // return default blank:false functionality
            }
            return true // else pass
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible in Grails to call the built in constraints from a custom constraint closure like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a custom constraint, not use the default nullable or blank constraint

```
class MyClass {
    boolean importMode
    String company

    static constraints = {
        company(validator: { val, obj ->
            if(!obj.importMode && !val) {
              return['myClass.company.required']
            }
        })
    }
}
```